# REST Assured getting map values only from response body

Tags: groovy, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

Imagine i called a RESTful service and it returns this in response body

```
[
  {
    "key": "Reason1 key",
    "values": {
      "en": "Reason1 English translation",
      "es": "Reason1 Spanish translation"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Reason2 key",
    "values": {
      "en": "Reason2 English translation",
      "es": "Reason2 Spanish translation"
    }
  }
]
```

**I need to get only values which map key is 'en'**

**So i am expecting the result to be like that after filtering it**

> ["Reason1 English translation", "Reason2 English translation"]
>
> OR
>
> {"Reason1 English translation", "Reason2 English translation"}

I had try this next code but still not completed

```
response.then().body("findAll { it }.collect { it.values }", hasItems("Reason1 English translation", "Reason2 English translation"))
```

and it return

> [{en=Reason1 English translation, es=Reason1 Spanish translation}, {en=Reason2 English translation, es=Reason2 Spanish translation}]

So how can i get only map values which matching map key condition of equality of 'en'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to `....body("findAll { it }.collect { it.values.en }"`

Add `en` to get the `en` nodes rather than the entire `values` node.

Comment: Very easy :) i was working on it as a map with key and value so i was trying .collect { it.values.key } and that's why it failed with me, but now it's working as it just working on JSON not Java object. (Thanks)